# File Upload Button in Data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload, datagridview

I am trying to use a file upload button in my datagridview so that it can invoke open file dialogue when clicked, but the only options i get in add columns for datagridview are different buttons(like datagridviewimage,datagridviewbutton) for which i could not generate button_click method. Please let me know if there is any way by which i can get a file upload button in my datagrid view.

Answer (score 2):

You can add cellClick event of datagridview and judge cell type.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex<0||e.RowIndex<0)
        {
           return;
        }
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        if (cell is DataGridViewButtonCell)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        } 
    }
```